# DTO per use case necessary in SOA?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, rest, soap, soa

I'm getting requirements that are asking for write and update of certain properties only but read of all properties so what I'm wondering what the best way to handle this is? I know this may sound crazy but the requirements are the writes/updates will be done via SOAP but the reads will be done via REST. The thought is the SOAP API will be used for initial data load, end-users of the web interface will makes more detailed modifications, then another set of end-users will program against the REST API to display data on web pages. I'd appreciate some feedback and/or comments on best/good practices. This is what I'm thinking needs to be done (note, abbreviated example):

```
namespace DTOs.Create
{
    public class Project
    {
        public string Name { get ; set; }
    }
}


namespace DTOs.Read
{
    public class Project
    {
        public string Name { get ; set; }
        public string Description { get ; set; }
        public DateTime DueDate { get ; set; }
        public int Priority { get ; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not achieve the the same with just one class property from namespace DTOs.Read and have 2 methods one REST which does a WebGet and not exposed via SOAP and the other methods (Create/Update) exposed via SOAP only.

Answer (score 0):

Think through the lifecycle of your implementation. If the rest and the soap interfaces might diverge over time, then sure go for two different DTO classes.

Specific in your situation, I would keep two DTOs around to loosen the two interfaces. I've heard too many times in projects things like "can't we just alter this lite part of the interface? It's just one string!" and then it costs too much effort to achieve because the interface are tightly coupled to other parts of the application that also has to be rewritten (retested) etc.

But it's pretty much depends on the scope of the application

Answer (score 0):

I would tend towards having just the one DTO, the intention of a DTO is to carry data, it should not have behavioural semantics attached to it, the service operation provides this.

You should be able to use the Project information (DTO) in many different contexts (in different operations).

The definition of what is a Project should remain consistent in your domain, if the definition of what defines a Project is different between the SOAP and REST part you have other problems.

The two interfaces can diverge over time, but the divergence is with how the data is used not what the data is.

If the one interface really requires such different information, rather create a new domain concept as it is not the original Project concept any more.